# How to Change angular excel export sheet name

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public save(component1: any, component2: any): void {

  Promise.all([component1.workbookOptions(), component2.workbookOptions()]).then(
   (workbooks) => {
     workbooks[0].sheets = 
     workbooks[0].sheets.concat(workbooks[1].sheets);
     component1.save(workbooks[0]);
   });
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you here. What are `component1`, `component2`? What is your current result and what is the different result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey I am using this link Code: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/how-to/export-to-separate-sheets/                                      
 and also I want to change "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" to custom name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that code, all your sheets are in `workbook[0].sheets`. This is an `Array` of [`WorkbookSheet`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/api/WorkbookSheet/); you can set the `name` property of each `WorkbookSheet` and that will be the name of each sheet in the final excel document.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4aotd?file=app/app.component.ts):

```js
public save(component1: any, component2: any): void {
    Promise.all([
      component1.workbookOptions(),
      component2.workbookOptions()
    ]).then(workbooks => {
      workbooks[0].sheets = workbooks[0].sheets.concat(workbooks[1].sheets);
      // The names are set here
      workbooks[0].sheets.forEach((sheet: WorkbookSheet, index: number) => {
        sheet.name = `Custom Sheet Name ${index}`;
      });
      component1.save(workbooks[0]);
    });
  }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: you saved me :)